# AssemblyScript: Dynamic local array size

Tags: javascript, webassembly, assemblyscript

Trying to create an array with a size that is a variable imported from the JS doesn't seem to work.
For example:

AssemblyScript:

```js
export declare arrSize: u32

const arr = new Uint32Array(arrSize)

export function init (): void {
  unchecked(testArr[0]) = 1
  store<u32>(0, unchecked(testArr[0]))
}
```

JS:

```js
const memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({ initial: 1 })
WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch('module.wasm'), {
  env: { memory },
  index: { arrSize: 2 }
}).then(module => {
  const { init } = module.instance.exports
  init()
  const arr = new Uint32Array(memory.buffer, 0, 2)
  console.log(arr)
})
```

Whereas if I change `const arr = new Uint32Array(2)` in the AssemblyScript file, it works.

Is there a way to have dynamically sized local arrays in the WebAssembly module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
export declare const count: i32;

const arr = new Array<i32>(count);
export function getCount(): i32 {
    return arr.length;
}
```

And in the imports object for `WebAssembly.instantiate` you should have:

```
{
    index: {
        count: 22
    }
}
```

provided that you assemblyscript file is named `index.ts`